# How to automatically duplicate a project in CVS

Tags: java, repository, cvs, rad

I have a java projet that is represented by a list of sub project as follows :

**APP1_Dependency**

**APP1_Ear**

**APP1_Parent**

**APP1_Properties**

**APP1_Web_InternetWeb**

I would like to make a copy of this project as follows

**APP2_Dependency**

**APP2_Ear**

**APP2_Parent**

**APP2_Properties**

**APP2_Web_InternetWeb**

My goal is to automatically update **APP2** whenever i make changes in **APP1**, the client wants **APP2** to act like an authentic copy of **APP1**.

I am using **RAD** as **IDE** and **CVS** as a repository.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use symlinks. I think it would be invisible to CVS.